# Image switch with data-attribute

Tags: jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
        $("header").addClass("sticky");
        $('header .logo a img').attr('src', $('header .logo a img').data("hover"));
    } else {
        $("header").removeClass("sticky");
        $("header").addClass("");
        $('header .logo a img').attr('src', $('header .logo a img').data("src"));
    }
});
```

The first one works but the src is not coming back anymore. How should this be done?

```
<img src="img/logo2.png" data-hover="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: Because you don't have data-src in your image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the `data-src` attribute that you try to access.

```
<img src="img/logo2.png" data-src="img/logo2.png" data-hover="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `.data("src")` the javascript is searching for `data-src` attribute on image element, but your image element has only `src`.

Don't use `.data`, better use `.attr("data-hover")` and `.attr("src")`

Comment: that will not work, since it has been overwritten by the previous action.

Comment: ah, you're right, but still, using `.attr` is better than `.data` in my opinion

Comment: Yes in this case the `.data('src')` is wrong as there is no such attribute specified.

Comment: Thanks guys! .attr("data-src") works bit repetition though but works :)